# Importing file contents as an array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im storing an array in a file like this:
[4, 2, 2][8, 2, 3][9, 3, 2][16, 2, 4][25, 5, 2][27, 3, 3][32, 2, 5][36, 6, 2][49, 7, 2][64, 2, 6][81, 3, 4][100, 10, 2][121, 11, 2][125, 5, 3]
However i cant find a way to retrive the data in a suitable format. What I need is for this data to be put into an array in a format where i can read the first number of the array eg. 4 or 8 or 9 or 16
and then pick one and read the next two numbers that follow, so for 16 it would be 2 and 4. I haven't been able to use the split() aproach as the output gets a but messy and doesnt nest the arrays: ['[4, 2, 2', '8, 2, 3', '9, 3, 2', '16, 2, 4]']. Is there a way to read the data while nesting the smaller arrays into the larger array encompasing all of it whiel still having the smaller arrays be readable?

If you have an idea about changing the way the data is stored in the file itself, I'm trying to keep the file as small as possible in size and making its contents have a high data to size efficiency so something like json would take up alot more space than just having the numbers written out. However if json is my only way to retrive the information then i would have to implement that.

Comment: You're asking/raising multiple questions. High storage efficiency would mean compression or binary formats. "Is there a way..." implies aiming for convenience, where text data formats like json or yaml could work. Also, please format your data correctly, otherwise it's unclear what exactly you're trying to store/retrieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you're working with numeric data, `numpy` should be the first tool you grab off the shelf. Here's an example of creating a numpy array, saving it to disk, saving it in a compressed format, loading it back, and selecting the first element of each row. There are probably things you can do to compress the file more, but this should get you started. I also added grabbing the back 2 elements of the first match in the first element, eg, `[2,4]`.

```
import numpy as np
import os
np_arr = np.asarray([[4, 2, 2], [8, 2, 3], [9, 3, 2], [16, 2, 4], [25, 5, 2], [27, 3, 3], [32, 2, 5],
                     [36, 6, 2], [49, 7, 2], [64, 2, 6], [81, 3, 4], [100, 10, 2], [121, 11, 2], [125, 5, 3]])
print(np_arr.shape)
np.savez('three_nums.npz',dta=np_arr, allow_pickle=False)  # for portability
np.savez_compressed('three_nums_cmp.npz', dta=np_arr, allow_pickle=False)  # for portability
uncmp, cmp = os.path.getsize('three_nums.npz'), os.path.getsize('three_nums_cmp.npz')
print(f"Uncompressed bytes: {uncmp}, compressed bytes: {cmp}, percent of orig: {cmp/uncmp:.2%}")
loadback = np.load('three_nums_cmp.npz')['dta']
first_elems = loadback[:,0]
print(first_elems.tolist())
print(loadback[loadback[:, 0] == 16,:][0][1:])
```

Yields:

```
(14, 3)
Uncompressed bytes: 685, compressed bytes: 469, percent of orig: 68.47%
[4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 125]
[2 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file `data.txt` looks like

```
[4, 2, 2][8, 2, 3][9, 3, 2][16, 2, 4][25, 5, 2][27, 3, 3][32, 2, 5][36, 6, 2][49, 7, 2][64, 2, 6][81, 3, 4][100, 10, 2][121, 11, 2][125, 5, 3]
```

then

```py
from pathlib import Path

data = Path("data.txt").read_text()
numbers = [list(map(int, row.split(","))) for row in data.strip("[]").split("][")]
```

gives you the following matrix (list of lists):

```py
[[4, 2, 2],
 [8, 2, 3],
 [9, 3, 2],
 [16, 2, 4],
 [25, 5, 2],
 [27, 3, 3],
 [32, 2, 5],
 [36, 6, 2],
 [49, 7, 2],
 [64, 2, 6],
 [81, 3, 4],
 [100, 10, 2],
 [121, 11, 2],
 [125, 5, 3]]
```

You could save the `numbers` in a CSV-file by using the `csv` module from the standard library:

```py
import csv

numbers = ...

# Writing
with open("data_new.csv", "w") as file:
    csv.writer(file).writerows(numbers)

# Reading
with open("data_new.csv", "r") as file:
    numbers = [list(map(int, row)) for row in csv.reader(file)]
```

You could also do that compressed by using the `gzip` module from the standard library:

```py
import gzip

numbers = ...

# Writing
with gzip.open("data.csv.gz", "w") as gz_file:
    gz_file.writelines((",".join(map(str, row)) + "\n").encode()
                       for row in numbers)

# Reading
with gzip.open("data.csv.gz", "r") as gz_file:
    numbers = [list(map(int, row.decode().split(","))) for row in gz_file]
```